# Dag is not visible on Airflow UI and not show in dags list

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I build a dag using this code:

```
from airlow import DAG
from airlow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1,1)
}

with DAG('parallel_dag', schedule_interval='@daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    task_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'task_1',
        bash_command = 'sleep 3'
    )

    task_2 = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'task_2',
        bash_command = 'sleep 3'
    )

    task_3 = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'task_3',
        bash_command = 'sleep 3'
    )

    task_4 = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'task_4',
        bash_command = 'sleep 3'
    )

    task_1 >> [task_2, task_3] >> task_4
```

And it is also not seen using `airflow dags list` in terminal only standard airflow dags is shown but no my.
And with location of my dag is all good it is located in dags folder

Comment: do you work on local airflow or docker ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your import statements. Airflow ignores files not containing “airflow” and “DAG”.  Your DAG File was not parsed since you have misspelled the word airflow.